# Getting Facebook friends' locations is time consuming

Tags: ruby, performance, algorithm, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In this algorithm I am looping through each friend to find their location, yet this is very inefficient... for 100 friends, this script takes over 2 minutes...can anyone suggest a more efficient solution?

> ```
> @friends[1..100].each do |f| # 'f' contains basic friend info (name, uid)
>   friend = get_friend(f['id']) # 'friend' gets data for each friend
>   if friend.has_key?('location')
>      @friends_locations[friend['name']] = friend['location']['name'] 
>     end
>   end
> ```

Im using Koala API and Ruby on Rails... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try FQL instead u can query/queries by post it throught REST API too
the query would be so ething like

select ... From user where hid in (select uid2 from friends where uid1 = me())

Comment: Isn't FQL getting deprecated?

Comment: I've cut it down to 30sec using your suggestion, thank you: @friends[1..100].each do |f|
      p @fb_api.fql_query("select name,current_location from user where uid = #{f['id']}")
    end

Answer (score 1):

You can send 20 queries at a time using [Batch Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/).  But FQL is probably a better approach and I haven't heard that it is deprecated.